# can't write dockerfile with installations of ubuntu, numpy, opencv

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

the plan is to deploy pretrained face recog-n model. But before i need to install some libs.

The idea behind docker is that it brings all the needed libs and builds entire 'env' without much overhead. One can just start dockerfile and it runs all other scripts in turn.

libs to install:

- Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
- Python 3.6.10 (3.5.x should be fine also)
- OpenCV 3.3.
- NumPy
- imutils https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils
- dlib http://dlib.net/
- face_recognition https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition

i m trying to use curl to download pkgs from URLs, but it's not working.

my dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04.6

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl bzip2 
    curl -o numpy
    && sudo apt-get install numpy
    && curl install imutils https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils
    && curl install dlib https://dlib.net
    && sudo git clone https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition.git
    && curl python-opencv https://opencv.org/
    && echo 'export PATH="~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc \
    &&  ~/anaconda3/bin/conda update -n base conda \
    &&  rm miniconda_install.sh \
    &&  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    &&  /bin/bash -c "source ~/.bashrc"

ENV PATH="~/anaconda3/bin:${PATH}"


##################################################
#    Setup env for current project:
##################################################

EXPOSE 8000

RUN /bin/bash -c "conda create -y -n PYMODEL3.6"

ADD requirements.txt /tmp/setup/requirements.txt

RUN /bin/bash -c "source activate PYMODEL3.6 && pip install -r /tmp/setup/requirements.txt"

WORKDIR /Service

ADD Service /Service

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "source activate PYMODEL3.6 && ./run.sh"]
```

the face model is pretrained. 
there are 2 python files that do actual detection, 128d encoding and recognition.
the usage is like this:

```
#detect face, if there is face - encode it, return pickle
python3 encode.py --dataset dataset_id --encodings encodings.pickle
--confidence 0.9

#recognize using pickle
python3 face_recognizer.py --encodings encodings.pickle --image
dataset_webcam/3_1.jpg --confidence 0.9 --tolerance 0.5
```

should I include them in the dockerfile?

Comment: Well if you are going to use those files in the process that your Dockerfile initiates, yes you have to include them.

Comment: @Shinratensei, that's the problem. i dont know how to make right working dockerfile

Comment: First of all, do you really need your version to be exactly Ubuntu 16.04.6? `FROM python:3.6.10` lets you use a well prepared Debian Buster with python 3.6.10 installed and ready to use. Also, you didn't need to install python with conda, the Docker container already gives you an environment to work in so you don't need to care about making virtual environments or anything like that.

Comment: Next, remember to create the folder where you add the requirements to the container, I guess `/tmp/setup` doesn't exist by default. Install the requirements with pip like `pip install -r /tmp/setup/requirements.txt`. Now, if your files `encode.py` and `face_recognizer.py` are inside your Service folder, it's all good. Otherwise, add them the same way you added the requirements and remember to check that you're adding them to existing folders and that your code is aware of that. Finally you can just you can just do `CMD ["./run.sh"]`

Answer (score 1):

I would propose you to use a Dockerfile like the following, assuming you have all your requirements (numpy, imutils, etc...) inside your requirements.txt file, and your `encode.py` and `face_recognizer.py` files in your `Service` folder:

```
FROM python:3.6.10

RUN mkdir /tmp/setup

ADD requirements.txt /tmp/setup/requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade setuptools && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir -r /tmp/setup/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /Service

ADD Service /Service/

CMD ["./run.sh"]

EXPOSE 8000
```

Comment: where is /tmp/setup folder created? i can't see it anywhere..

Comment: Inside the container. access it with `docker exec -it your_container_name bash`. Isn't it there? Otherwise you can add it anywhere else that isn't a temporal folder.